# Programming Error while creating MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, create-table, mysql-connector-python

@I am translating input from a user into a MySQL command but it says i have the syntax wrong and Idk how I can fix it. Essentially I made a program in python (not a problem with the python code) that has the ability to create MySQL tables and translates user input into a MySQL command to create the table, but I think i have worded the command wrong and need someone to help explain what I did wrong and how I can fix it or another way to do it (no new python packages just different MySQL command).

```py
#Error
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''c1', 'c2') VALUES [('r1', 'r2')]' at line 1

#here is what i was collecting in my attempt to fix the bug
'''
ROW SYNTAX: [('r1', 'r2')]
COLUMN SYNTAX: ('c1', 'c2')
MySQL COMMAND: CREATE TABLE test ('c1', 'c2') VALUES [('r1', 'r2')]
'''
#just the values none of the ROW SYNTAX or COLUMN SYNTAX is actually put into the mysql command
```

I was expecting it to create the table with:

2 columns: c1 and c2

1 row with 2 values: r1 and r2

Yet as I have explained above... it doesn't. I don't work with MySQL just python really so I'm probably missing something really easy or big that I just don't understand.

i've seen some example syntax similar to this but again I don't understand it.

## UPDATE

```py
'''
ROW SYNTAX: [('r1', 'r3'), ('r2', 'r4')]
COLUMN SYNTAX TCOLN: (c1, c2)
COLUMN SYNTAX COLNAMES: (c1 VCHAR(255), c2 VCHAR(255))

CREATE TABLE COMMAND: CREATE TABLE test (c1 VCHAR(255), c2 VCHAR(255));
INSERT TABLE COMMAND: INSERT INTO test (c1, c2) VALUES [('r1', 'r3'), ('r2', 'r4')];
'''
'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 472, in cmd_query
    raw_as_string=raw_as_string)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VCHAR(255), c2 VCHAR(255))' at line 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 558, in ctable
    cursor.execute(sqlCol) #slqCol is CREATE TABLE test (c1 VCHAR(255), c2 VCHAR(255));
  line 266, in execute
    raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)
  line 475, in cmd_query
    sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VCHAR(255), c2 VCHAR(255))' at line 1
'''
```

Thanks to your suggestions i am using VARCHAR now but i still seem to be running into close to the same problem

Thanks to @Martin for explaining what varchar is ect, it also turns out VCHAR is not the same as VARCHAR (thanks @robsiemb). Now the table is creating BUT not putting the data values in? (this might be a python problem, hope not)

````py
'''
INSERT TABLE COMMAND: INSERT INTO test (c1, c2) VALUES ('r1', 'r2'),('rr1', 'rr2');
'''

# LATEST UPDATE
New Error when inserting values
```python

#CREATE TABLE COMMAND: CREATE TABLE test (c1 VARCHAR(255), c2 VARCHAR(255));
#INSERT TABLE COMMAND: INSERT INTO test (c1, c2) VALUES (r1,r3),(r2,r4);

'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 472, in cmd_query
    raw_as_string=raw_as_string)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Unknown column 'r1' in 'field list'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 563, in ctable
    cursor.execute(sqlVal)
  line 266, in execute
    raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)
  line 475, in cmd_query
    sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'r1' in 'field list'
'''
````

Python problem, thanks for answering my question!

Comment: You should check the syntax of Create Table. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

Comment: I did but I don't understand it xD, I need like super simple terms like
Create table [table name] [column name] VALUES [(row value for first column)]

Comment: was both the syntaxing and i was missing a commit statement (python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with what you are doing is in this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE test ('c1', 'c2') VALUES [('r1', 'r2')]
```

This is not a valid `CREATE TABLE` statement.

It looks like you're trying to create the table, and then insert some values into it.  Is that the case?

If so, this should be broken into two statements.  First create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (c1 DATATYPE, c2 DATATYPE);
```

Replace `DATATYPE` with the type of the column you are creating (i.e. `INT`, `VARCHAR(10)`, etc.).

Second, insert your values into the table:

```
INSERT INTO test (c1, c2) VALUES (r1, r2);
```

Comment: i'm defaulting all my data types to strings at the moment, how would i do that?

Comment: @Cosmic I would recommend not storing values in string-only columns. MySQL has a plethora of types available for data storage.  However, `VARCHAR` is typically the appropriate data type for string data.

Comment: @Cosmic Yes that is right, although with `VARCHAR` you should specify the size of the column (the number of characters it can contain).  Ex: `VARCHAR(10)` can hold 10 characters.

Comment: so would VARCHAR(255) be good (the user can't change it) so its not too short? i read that above 255 something else happens with bytes

Comment: @Cosmic A `VARCHAR` can _technically_ go up to 65K in size.  However, if you are regularly stored very long strings, I'd recommend a `TEXT` column instead.  With a `VARCHAR`, only the amount of space needed is used (plus a little overhead).  Hence, `VARCHAR` = variable length characters

Comment: i've tried what you said but i stil can seem to get it to work? updated post with problem

Comment: @Cosmic Your `VALUES` list shouldn't have a square bracket around it. This is not valid: `[(r1, r2), (r1, r2)]`. Remove the square brackets

Answer (score 0):

You should review the [syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) and [example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/creating-tables.html) for how to create a MySQL table.

There are 2 issues with your CREATE TABLE statement.

- You need to specify the types of the columns, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE test (c1 INTEGER, c2 INTEGER);
```

- You can't supply the values at the same time as create, but you can follow up with an [insert statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html):

```
INSERT INTO test (c1, c2) VALUES (1, 3),(2, 4);
```

The above gives a table with two rows, like this:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+------+------+
| c1   | c2   |
+------+------+
|    1 |    3 |
|    2 |    4 |
+------+------+
```

Comment: Updated my post with my problem after doing similar to what you guys said

Comment: @Cosmic Your updated query says "VCHAR" not "VARCHAR" (see the allowable [string types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html)), and your insert has square brackets which are not allowed.  Again, I urge you to review the syntax and examples in the documentation.